# How to export a type alias for an existing class

Tags: typescript, nativescript, typescript-typings

I have a TS module that is deeply nested in namespaces. I can't avoid this because it is auto-generated from a java library (I am writing nativescript).

I want to "re-export" these nested classes in my own module, at the top level.

Say I have a class that is declared as such in `native-types.d.ts`:

```
declare module com {
    export module esp32 {
        export module blufi {
            export class BlufiClient {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The in my own module's code `index.ts`:

```
export type BlufiClient = com.esp32.blufi.BlufiClient;
```

The auto-generated declarations file `index.d.ts`:

```
export declare type BlufiClient = com.esp32.blufi.BlufiClient;
```

The goal here is to allow the users of my module to do something like:

```js
import { BlufiClient } from 'nativescript-blufi';

const client = new BlufiClient(...);
```

But the error I get when trying to `new` the class is:

> 'BlufiClient' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
> here.

Initially, I thought I had to `export type BlufiClient = typeof ...` but that didn't work, and it makes sense that it didn't because it's pointing to a class, not a constructor or a member.

How can I achieve this?

To attempt to illustrate the issue more clearly, here is an example project you can run in your browser:
https://playcode.io/849389

In this example, `native_module.ts` is the module I have no control over, and must remain as-is.

`my_module.ts` is where I am trying to "re-export" the classes in `native_module.ts` so that they are available without having to write out the full module path (i.e. com.esp32.blufi...). I also hope to add some additional functionality in `my_module` that isn't available in `native_module` in the future.

Finally, `test_module.ts` simply tries to instantiate the "re-exported" class. You can see the error I am getting.

Comment: A `class` declaration has a type (corresponding to its instance type) and a value (corresponding to the class constructor) and you presumably need to export them both.  Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6XgDm) work for you?  It's hard to tell without a [mre] I can drop into a standalone IDE.  If it works I can write up an answer; if not, please consider [edit]ing the question with an example that demonstrates the issue you're seeing (possibly with a link to a web IDE project if you need multiple files to show the problem).

Comment: @jcalz Yes, your suggestion worked. I am baffled that there is no way to simple export a class in one line. My issue now is that TCS will compile you suggestion to:
`export declare type BlufiClient = com.esp32.blufi.BlufiClient;
export declare const BlufiClient: typeof com.esp32.blufi.BlufiClient;` Which results in the same error. I had to manually change it to your suggestion...

Comment: @jcalz I have added a MRE in case you can come up with a better way now that is is clearer. See my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Does `export import` work for you like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbG5PW)?  What is "TCS"?  Can you give a [mre] that demonstrates the "Which results in the same error" part?

Comment: @jcalz Yes `export import` does exactly what I was hoping, though I do have to include a `/// <reference ...>` to the original class declarations. I am not able to find much about the usage of `import var =`. What is the difference between `import`ing from an ambient module and just using it as-is?

Comment: The `import x = y` syntax [creates an alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases) that can be re-exported.  Would you like me to write this up as an answer?  I don't know what to say about the `/// <reference` issue unless I see a [mre] in front of me that demonstrates it.

Comment: @jcalz Oh the `/// <reference ...>` is no problem, I was just mentioning a step I had to take to get it working. You can write the `import x = y` as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks for the information, I ended up reading about modules/importing/exporting again thanks to your help. I thought I had understood it, but I had not :).